# Plot multiple time series with different time indices in R using xts

Tags: r, plot, xts

Using R, I have a several time series and they have different time indices, like

```
 date.a<-seq(as.Date('2014-01-01'),as.Date('2014-02-01'),by = 2)
 date.b<-seq(as.Date('2014-01-01'),as.Date('2014-02-15'),by = 3)
 df.a <- data.frame(time=date.a, A=sin((1:16)*pi/8))
 df.b <- data.frame(time=date.b, B=cos((1:16)*pi/8))
```

I merge them into one `xts` time series using

```
my.ts <- merge(xts(df.a$A,df.a$time),xts(df.b$B,df.b$time))
```

I want to display them both, either on separate panels, or in different colors in one.

**Update:**

Using `xtsExtra`, I was able to display both series in one plot or each in a separate panel, using the following commands:

```
#one panel, different colors
plot(my.ts, screens=1, type="p")
#two panels, same color
plot(my.ts, screens=c(1,2), type="p")
```

This approach only works with `type="p"` - plotting lines will not show the whole series, and create discontinuities. This is probably caused by the `NA`s which were caused by merging the series. Which options do I have to work with these `NA`s? I've found some, but I am not confident they are the best way.

1. `na.omit(my.ts)` and `na.exclude(my.ts)` seem to be too greedy - they only keep rows where both columns are not `NA`. How do I chance this behavior to only a rowwise operation?
2. `na.approx(my.ts)` fills up the `NA`s, but I am wondering if this linear approximation is creating artificial data points which would make the plot look differently.
3. The best way, in my opinion, would be an option which could be passed to plot to tell what should be done with `NA`s. Is there such a thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `na.approx`.  Also note that zoo, which is already loaded by xts, is used here:

```
z <- na.approx(as.zoo(my.ts))

# plot.zoo
plot(z, screen = 1, col = 1:2, ylab = "Y", xlab = "")

# xyplot.zoo
library(lattice)
xyplot(z, screen = 1, col = 1:2, ylab = "Y", xlab = "")

# autoplot.zoo
library(ggplot2)
autoplot(z, facet = NULL) + ylab("Y")
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should do it without `xts` (dont see the need for it)
With `ggplot2` a Solution might be

```
    require(ggplot2)
ggplot()+geom_line(aes(x=time,y=A),data=df.a, col=2)+
  geom_line(aes(x=time,y=B),data=df.b,col=3) + ylab("")
```

[image: ggplot2 two time series]

Comment: I'm planning to use `PerformanceAnalytics` which is based on `xts`, so I'd like to understand how to do the commands within this package - transforming to `data.frame`s in order to plot doesn't seem to be very elegant. However, I found an option which specifies what to do with multivariate time series, although I don't fully understand what to do with it. My question is going to be amended appropriately.